# How do I convert Excel formula to DAX

Tags: excel, dax

I am currently migrating Excel reports to Power BI. I need help converting the excel formulas to DAX.

= DATEVALUE(TEXT([@[ClosedCaseDate]],”m/yyyy”))

= DATEVALUE(TEXT([@[ClosedCaseDate]],”m/d/yyyy”))-WEEKDAY([@[ClosedCaseDate]])+1

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you converting a date to text just to convert it back to a date?

Answer (score 0):

Same function in DAX:

```
DATEVALUE(date_text)
```

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datevalue-function-dax